# $2013!$ ends in a string of zeros. How many of them are there?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

$2013!$ ends in a string of zeros. How many of them
are there?

**Work**

**The answer is given like this:**(Kindly explain why this is so)

$2$’s and $5$’s pair off to produce multiples of 10 and since there are more 2’s than 5’s
in the prime factorisation of $2013!$ we need to find the number of 5’s in this
factorisation.

$\frac{2013}5=402$ numbers are multiples of 5

$\frac{2013}{25} =80$ numbers are multiples of $5^2$

$\frac {2013} {5^3}=16$ numbers are multiples of $5^ 3$

$\frac {2013}{5^4}=3$ numbers are multiples of $5^4$

$\mbox{402+80+16+3 = 501}$ numbers are there in total so there will be 501 zeroes.

Comment: Which part of the argument you don't understand?

Comment: This method is known as [Legendre's formula](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Legendre%27s_Formula). See the link for a very nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you factor $2013!$ and take the exponent on $5$, that's your answer. For example:
$$
5! = 120 = 5^1 3^1 2^3 \Rightarrow 1\;\text{zero}\\
6! = 720 = 5^1\dots \Rightarrow 1\;\text{zero}\\
10! = 3,628,800 = \dots 5^2\dots \Rightarrow 2\;\text{zeros}\\
15! = 1,307,674,368,000 = \dots 5^3\dots \Rightarrow 3\;\text{zeros}
$$
But notice that when you get to $25$, this number will contribute to $+2$ on the exponent of $5$:
$$
20! = 20\dots 15\dots 10\dots 5\dots = \dots 5^4\dots \Rightarrow 4\;\text{zeros}\\
25! = 25\dots 20\dots 15\dots 10\dots 5\dots = \dots 5^6\dots \Rightarrow 6\;\text{zeros}
$$
That's why you count the multiples of $5$, then add $+1$ for each multiple of $25$, and so on for $125$, etc.